# How can I tell the index of an array of objects in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of todos `[Todo1, Todo2, Todo3]`

Each object has an attribute, `:done_date`

I need to find the *first* instance of the object where `:done_date => null`

THEN I need to know what index it is `todos[N]` so I can find the object before `todos[N-1]`

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what defines _first_. In SQL (Set Query Language), there is no defined order. You will get them in a random order. If the order is already defined, so you have the array, use: `ind = array.find_index {|t|t.done_date == nil}`.

Comment: Right, that was the next part -- I need to sort it by original_date, how would I do that?

Comment: `array.sort{|a,b| a.original_date <=> b.original_date}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try going about it in a slightly different way.  Making use of Ruby's [`Enumerable#take_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001519):

```
# assuming 'todos' holds your todo objects
todos.take_while { |todo| todo.done_date != nil }.last
```

This will get all todo objects from `todos` until it sees a nil `done_date`, and then grab the last one.  You'll have the last todo item before the first nil `done_date`.

So, if you have

```
todos = [todo1, todo2, todo3, todo4_with_null_done_date]
```

the code example above will return `todo3`.

That said, if you're *really* looking for something that makes use of the array's indicies, you could try something like this as well:

```
first_nil_index = todos.find_index { |todo| todo.done_date.nil? }
todos[first_nil_index - 1]
```